# Is there a way to saveFrame in processing one at a time without capturing many pictures?

Tags: java, canvas, processing, draw

I realized that saving the frame as a function in the draw block was a disadvantage because it captured so much data just once the mouse was pressed. I tried placing it into the setup block, but that only captures the original canvas. I also tried having a mouse pressed function in the setup block, but that didn't work either.

Is there a way to have the save frame element only once the user has finished drawing on the canvas?

```
void setup(){
 size(900,900);
 background(25, 57,0);
 }

 void draw(){
  if(mousePressed){
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,30,40);
  fill(255,255,255);
  stroke(200,100,100);
  }
  if(keyPressed==true){
  background(25,57,0);
   }



  saveFrame();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no way of testing it right now, but here's a way to do this. It's not the only one but you may like it: use a boolean to automatically save exactly when the user release the mouse button. Here's how:

```
bool _saved = false;

void setup(){
   size(900,900);
   background(25, 57,0);
 }

 void draw(){
  if(mousePressed){
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,30,40);
    fill(255,255,255);
    stroke(200,100,100);
  else if (!_saved){
    saveFrame();
  }
  
  if(keyPressed==true){
    background(25,57,0);
  }    

  saveFrame();
    _saved = true;
    // stuff
  }
```

Please bear in mind that I am in no position to test the code snippet, so there may be an error somewhere in there. I am sorry if it's the case.

Anyway, have fun!

Answer (score 1):

@laancelot beat me to it :)))

My suggestion was the same, just different formatting:

```
color backgroundColor = color(25, 57, 0);

boolean isSavingFrame;

void setup() {
  size(900, 900);
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  stroke(200, 100, 100);
  background(backgroundColor);
}

void draw() {
  if (mousePressed) {
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 30, 40);    
  }
  
  if(isSavingFrame){
    saveFrame();
    isSavingFrame = false;
  }
}

void keyPressed(){
  // press DELETE/BACKSPACE to clear
  if(keyCode == DELETE || keyCode == BACKSPACE){
    background(backgroundColor);
  } 
  // press 's' to save
  if(key == 's'){
    isSavingFrame = true; 
  }
}
```

You can see the same logic in the [DXF Export example](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/dxf/index.html)